# How to deal with a lot variables access in different function/class in python

Tags: python, variables

The code which I wanna improved now looks something like below,
which f0 and f1(or more than 2 function) need the same variables.
I have to code about 50 lines to describe the variable setting at each function.
how can I do this more pythontic?

--f0.py

```
import csv
def gen(csv_f): 
    # var define
    for row in csv.DictReader(open(csv_f)):
        c += row['x']
        ...
    a  = 1
    b  = 2
    ...
    # do sth in f0
    xx = a + b
    ...
    str = ...
    return str
```

--f1.py

```
import csv  
def gen(csv_f): 
    # var define
    for row in csv.DictReader(open(csv_f)):
        c += row['x']
        ...
    a  = 1
    b  = 2
    ...
    # do sth in f1
    xx = a*b + b
    ...
    str = ...
    return str
```

--genstr.py

```
from f0 import *
from f1 import *

f = open('xxx.x','w')
f.write(f0.gen(1)+f1.gen(1))
f.close()
```

---

(I don't really know how to use class, but I found this could help my problem
 just describe maybe it will help understanding my question )
I try to do it with class, so i can access by inherit conf.
I know I can access by 'self.a', but is there any way I can direct use 'a' in the function?

--conf.py

```
class conf:
    def __init__(self, csv_f):
        # var define
        for row in csv.DictReader(open(csv_f)):
            c += row['x']
            ...
        self.a  = 1
        self.b  = 2
        ...
```

--f0.py

```
import conf
class f0(conf):
    def __init__(self):
        config.__init__(self, csv_f) #this line is not correct
    def gen():
        # var set
        c = self.c
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        # do sth in f0
        xx = a + b
        ...
        str = ...
        return str
```

--f1.py

```
import conf
class f1(conf):
    def __init__(self):
        config.__init__(self, csv_f) #this line is not correct
    def gen():
        # var set
        c = self.c
        a = self.a
        b = self.b
        # do sth in f1
        xx = a + b
        ...
        str = ...
        return str
```

--genstr.py

```
from f0 import *
from f1 import *

f = open('xxx.x','w')
f.write(f0.gen(1)+f1.gen(1))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is slightly confusing and i'm not sure what exactly you are trying, but here are some general help.

This code:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(open(csv_f)):
    c += row['x']
```

Will append the content of coloumn `x` to `c`.

```
import conf
class f0(conf):
    def __init__(self, csv_f):
         super(f0,self).__init__(self)  # Fixed
         self.csv_f = csv_f

    def gen(self):
         # var set
         c = self.c # 
         a = self.a
         b = self.b
         # do sth in f0
         xx = a + b
```

Instead of `c = self.c` you can use `self.c`  where ever you need `c`.

```
from f0 import *
from f1 import *

f = open('xxx.x','w') 
f.write(f0(filename).gen()+f1(filename).gen())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first two functions differ in these lines:

```
xx = a + b
```

vs.

```
xx = a*b + b
```

You can pass in this as as additional argument.

```
def gen(csv_f, f): 
    # var define
    for row in csv.DictReader(open(csv_f)):
        c += row['x']
        ...
    a  = 1
    b  = 2
    ...
    # use the passed function
    xx = f(a, b)
    ...
    return str

l0 = lambda a, b: a + b
l1 = lambda a, b: a * b + b

# call gen with one of these lambdas as the second argument
gen(1, l0)
gen(1, l1)
```